# ¿Por qué las expresiones traducidas del español al inglés no se escriben exáctamente igual?

Tags: traducción, gramática

Planteo esta pregunta debido a que he recordado un ejemplo donde en muchos casos similares suelo tener esta duda y me gustaría leer y aprender más al respecto.

Un ejemplo de lo que pregunto es:

> Command Line - Línea de comandos.

Como se puede observar, en lugar de ser *Comando Linea*, se traduce *Línea de Comando*. Y no sólo se invierte el orden, sino que también se agrega "de".

¿Cuál es la regla que dicta que esto sea de esta forma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El idioma español y, en su nombre, la *Gramática española* son los que dictan que eso sea así.

Partamos de que "línea" y "comando" son dos sustantivos. La gramática inglesa dicta que un sustantivo puede adjetivizar a otro. Así, en "command line" el sustantivo *command* está adjetivizando a *line*. Sería como si en español dijéramos "línea comandesca". Sin embargo, la gramática española dice que cuando dos sustantivos están relacionados, afectando el uno al otro, se deben relacionar con el empleo de la preposición *de*, anteponiendo el sustantivo más general seguido del que crea el caso particular:

> Bocata de chorizo.
>   Dolor de barriga.
>   Bolso de cuero.
>   Pañuelo de bolsillo.
>   Etc.

Cada uno de estos ejemplos en inglés se podría expresar con un sustantivo adjetivizado: *chorizo sandwich*, *stomach ache*, *leather bag*, etc. Pero no es así en español: no decimos *bocata choricero*, *dolor barrigoso* ni *bolso encuerado*. Del mismo modo, no decimos *línea comandesca* como propuse, sino *línea de comandos* (primero *línea* como sustantivo general, y luego *de comandos* para especificar el tipo particular de línea).

En general, cada idioma tiene sus normas dictadas por la gramática que hay que seguir, y es importante aprenderlas. Por ejemplo, si todavía habláramos latín igual la frase se habría aproximado un poco más al inglés, dado que sería algo así como "līnea ordinātiōnum"<sup>1</sup>, con el sustantivo *ordinātiō* conjugado en genitivo plural. Aún así tendrías que colocar primero el sustantivo general, igual que en español, y luego el adjetivizado. Y en esperanto, idioma de invención relativamente reciente, se dice *komandlinia*, muy cercano a "command line", con el sustantivo adjetivizante unido al general.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>En latín en realidad es *linea imperandi*, "línea que da órdenes".</sub>

Comment: Lo estoy entendiendo poco a poco e intentando aplicarlo con otras palabras. Tengo un enredo de conceptos... Entonces, esto que indicas en la línea (primero línea como sustantivo general, y luego de comandos para especificar el tipo particular de línea) es porque en el idioma inglés, como me ha mencionado, indica que command está adjetivizando a line (adjetivo calificativo)?

Comment: @MarianoM exacto. De todas formas, si tu duda es más sobre el idioma inglés, tal vez debas dirigirte al foro de este idioma. Y luego así en general, una vez aprendes que cada idioma tiene su propia gramática, descubres que muy pocas veces vas a acertar traduciendo una frase palabra por palabra. :-)

Comment: We can famously string many nouns together like "aluminium soup pot lid clearance sale bargain" but as Charlie states that does not work in many other languages. I have no idea why and the Linguistics site is probably the one for the origina of language difference.

Comment: @Charlie Muchas gracias! Tenía esta duda hace rato y el resolverla me está causando más curiosidad para seguir adelante. ¿Qué quieres decir con que muy pocas veces voy a acertar traduciendo una frase palabra por palabra? ¿Crees que es mejor aprender frases armadas?

Comment: @MarianoM es la conclusión que se saca con este tipo de ejemplos. Si traduces "command line" como "comando línea" y lo dices así en español, la gente no es que te vaya a mirar raro, es que no te va a entender. Cada idioma tiene su propia forma de expresar conceptos, y por eso no le pides a una chica su teléfono número, sino su número de teléfono. Lo que hay que aprender es eso, cómo cada idioma expresa los conceptos y descubrir cuáles son las correlaciones entre ellos.

Comment: @Charlie Perfecto, voy a seguir repasando y poniendo en práctica esto. Pero siendo honesto, ya he intentado tantas veces pidiendo el número de teléfono que pedir el teléfono número tal vez me termine resultando más eficaz jaja. Gracias por todo nuevamente.

Comment: Casi, casi off-topic.

Comment: Un idioma no es sólo sus palabras (léxico) sino cómo se forman y relacionan entre ellas ([morfosintaxis](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morfosintaxis)). Por eso es que no se puede aprender un idioma aprendiéndose sólo las definiciones de un diccionario.

Comment: @DGaleano Lo sospechaba antes de preguntarlo, pero, preferí arriesgarme. Gracias por permitir recibir respuestas, le puede ser útil a otras personas también. La próxima seré más puntual.

Comment: @pablodf76 Claro, entiendo eso, en nuestro idioma pasa lo mismo. El uso y significado de las palabras es para un lenguaje más formal, después está las relaciones entre ellas. Algunos me han recomendado no empezar a preocuparme tanto por la gramática al momento de aprender inglés, esto me haría complicar el aprendizaje. Y en cierto grado creo que tienen razón, pero prefiero ir tratando de llevarlo a la par porque hay muchos conceptos que había olvidado o que han quedado sin entender desde la secundaria.